# High CPU usage from jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cpu-usage

There is a specific set of actions that cause the website that I am building on my localhost to freeze and cause the **CPU usage to jump up to 25%** or so.

I am building a sort of **tree structure**, where the child row is loaded depending on the currently selected parent node. So, it is necessary for me to be able to save and load the objects which contain the information for all of the children, depending on the selected parent.

**The issue occurs when I am trying to update the information of a previously made child row.** I tell it, which will be easier to see in code, to check for any saved child row with the same parent, and, if there is a saved child row with the same parent, **it stores the info of 6 textArea values** for each child in the child row.

I believe that I am having this trouble because I have jquery at the top of my php file, and I have a javascript file linked at the bottom of my php file. **Both of these files have eventListeners for the same button**, which I believe to be causing the high CPU usage.

Is this a bad practice? Are there ways around it? Should I move all of my javascript at the bottom of my page, to the top of my page? What steps should I take to properly identify code causing high CPU usage?

**Side Note: This code is as minimum and sufficient as possible. I can provide much more if necessary.**

PHP:

```
<?php
    include_once 'header.php';
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="essayTree.css">

<section class="account-main-container">
    <div class="account-main-wrapper">
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>EssayTree</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script>
            var childObjects = [];
            var mostRecentParentClicked = "";
            var newItem;
            var childTextObject = function(parent, texts){
                this.parent = parent;
                this.texts = texts;
            };

            var isNewChildRow = function(parent){
                for(i=0;i<childObjects.length;i++){
                    if(childObjects[i].parent === parent){
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                if(childObjects.length === 0){
                    return true;
                }
            };

            var indexOfChildRow = function(parent){
                for(i=0;i<childObjects.length; i++){
                    if(childObjects[i].parent === parent){
                        return i;
                    } else {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
            };

            //Listener for the most recent parentText clicked
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.parentText').click(function(){
                    mostRecentParentClicked = $(document.activeElement).attr('id');
                });
            });

            //THIS PART RIGHT HERE STARTED CAUSING THE HIGH CPU USAGE
            //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('button#saveInfo').click(function(){
                    if(isNewChildRow(mostRecentParentClicked)){
                        newItem = new evidenceTextObject(mostRecentParentClicked, ["", "", "", "", "", ""]);

                        for(i=0;i<6;i++){
                            newItem.texts[i] = $('#childText' + (i+1)).val();
                        }
                    } else {                        
                        for(i=0;i<6;i++){
                            childObjects[indexOfChildRow(mostRecentParentClicked)].texts[i] = 
$('#childText' + (i+1)).val();
                        }
                    }

                    childObjects.push(newItem);
                });
            });


        </script> 
        </head>

        <body>


            <div id="top">


            <div id="parentParagraphs">

                <div id="firstParentRow" class="w3-row">
                    <div id="parent1" class="w3-col s4">
                        <h2>parent #1</h2>
                        <textArea id="parentText1" class="parentText"></textArea>
                    </div>
                    <div id="parent2" class="w3-col s4">
                        <h2>Body #2</h2>
                        <textArea id="parentText2" class="parentText"></textArea>
                    </div>
                    <div id="parent3" class="w3-col s4">
                        <h2>parent #3</h2>
                        <textArea id="parentText3" class="parentText"></textArea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="secondParentRow" class="w3-row">
                    <div id="parent4" class="w3-col s4">
                        <h2>parent #4</h2>
                        <textArea id="parentText4" class="parentText"></textArea>
                    </div>
                    <div id="parent5" class="w3-col s4">
                        <h2>Body #5</h2>
                        <textArea id="parentText5" class="parentText"></textArea>
                    </div>
                    <div id="parent6" class="w3-col s4">
                        <h2>Body #6</h2>
                        <textArea id="parentText6" class="parentText"></textArea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button id="selectParent" type="button">Select</button>

                <div id="middle">

                    <div id="children">

                        <div id="firstChildRow" class="w3-row">
                            <div id="child1" class="w3-col s4">
                                <h2>child #1</h2>
                                <textArea id="childText1" class="childText"></textArea>
                            </div>
                            <div id="child2" class="w3-col s4">
                                <h2>child #2</h2>
                                <textArea id="childText2" class="childText"></textArea>
                            </div>
                            <div id="child3" class="w3-col s4">
                                <h2>child #3</h2>
                                <textArea id="childText3" class="childText"></textArea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="secondChildRow" class="w3-row">
                            <div id="child4" class="w3-col s4">
                                <h2>child #4</h2>
                                <textArea id="childText4" class="childText"></textArea>
                            </div>
                            <div id="child5" class="w3-col s4">
                                <h2>child #5</h2>
                                <textArea id="childText5" class="childText"></textArea>
                            </div>
                            <div id="child6" class="w3-col s4">
                                <h2>child #6</h2>
                                <textArea id="childText6" class="childText"></textArea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            //THIS IS THE BUTTON THAT IS CAUSING THE ISSUE
                  //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                            <button id="saveInfo" type="button">Save All Children</button>


                    </div>        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        </div>

        //THIS PART RIGHT HERE HAS AN EVENT LISTENER FOR THE SAME BUTTON
        //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        <script type="text/javascript" src="essayTree.js"></script> 
        </body>
        </html>
    </div>

</section>

<?php
    include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

So as you can see I have marked the jquery code that was causing issues at the top of this code, and I have also marked the javascript file that I believe to be interfering with it.

I will now put the javascript code for the event listener that is for the same button.

Javascript:

```
var childController = (function(){
    var childObjects = [];

    var childObject = function(name, parent, info){
      this.name = name;
      this.parent = parent;
      this.info = info;
    };

     var indexOfChildObject = function(name, parent){
      var location = -1;

      for(i=0;i<childObjects.length;i++){
        if(childObjects[i].name === name && childObjects[i].parent === parent){
          location = i;
        }
      }

      return{
        index: location
      }
    };

    var storeChildren = function(index){
      for(i=0;i<6;i++){
        parentObjects[index].children[i] = document.getElementById("childText" + (i+1)).value;
      }
    };

      //THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT HAS AN EVENT LISTENER FOR THE SAME BUTTON
      //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      var saveButton = function(){
      document.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if(document.activeElement.id === "saveInfo" && doms.saveInfo.innerHTML === "Save All Children){
          storeChildren(indexOfParentObject(selectedParent).index);
        }
      });
    };
    return{
        init: function(){
             saveButton();
        }
    }
})();

childController.init();
```

Comment: This code is clearly not as minimum and sufficient as possible. It's rather longer than needed and things like header, footer, and CSS, are missing. If they are not needed they shouldn't be included in question.

Comment: Your comment distracts from my question. While yes, it is maybe 98% minimum and sufficient, those 5-10 lines do add some context.

Comment: I am really in need of help here. If someone has an idea of a direction to point me in, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the lack of [a complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example doesn't help your question. Apart from that, I would suggest using the debugger build into your browser (`[F12]`?) and set some breakpoints in critical areas.

Comment: Honestly, I have followed every single step listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and you are objectively wrong to say that i have not.

I can understand if you are having a hard time with the question since there is a lot going on, but I would be more than happy to clarify anything that you find confusing.

Comment: I can try asking this question again with minimal  content, but it will not be sufficient. To make this question more readable to others I would have to get rid of necessary information. If I do end up needing to ask this question again in an abridged version. I will make sure to leave a link this question for clarification and elaboration purposes.

Comment: OK, I copied all your codes and tried to make a working example, without luck. There are really serious errors in your HTML and Javascript. I also cannot find your `essayTree.js` script. How am I objectively wrong? Have you tried to debug anything yourself?

Comment: essayTree.js is the javascript that I have provided. I think at this point it'd be easier to send my entire htdocs folder haha

Comment: My code is missing some javascript. I have not elaborated on parentObjects[index].children[i]. The reason for this is because I thought it would be too much extra code, and I was trying to keep it as minimum as possible initially.

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense that that's `essayTree.js`. I still cannot make it work, I get errors in the console. Why don't you upload a working example somewhere. You can also do it on things like http://phptester.net , http://phpfiddle.org or upload it somewhere like to https://wetransfer.com . My point is: It is very hard to know why your code does, what it does, if we cannot reproduce the problem you report.