# High CPU usage from event listeners?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cpu

When I added a new event listener to a button in my jquery code, responding to the button click in a specific way (the specific way is clarified here: [High CPU usage from jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505611/high-cpu-usage-from-jquery)) caused the web page to freeze and the CPU usage jumped up to 25%.

My php code looks something like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>EssayTree</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
            $('button#saveInfo').click(function(){
                //jquery code for button

            });
     });
</head>
<body>
//Lots of html




    //This javascript has an event listener for the same button as above
<script type="text/javascript" src="essayTree.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

I think the issue is that I have an event listener above and below the html that it references reacting to the same button click. But, I really do not know if this is the problem.

**Is it bad practice to have event listeners for the same button click above and below the html that it references? If not, what other steps can I take?**

If you are reading this and want more code for clarification purposes please check out this question: [High CPU usage from jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505611/high-cpu-usage-from-jquery) .

I had to ask this question again because making the question minimum and sufficient made for a lot of code. So what is presented here is an attempt to make it readable by making it more minimal, and now I have provided a link for the sufficient information.

I hope these edits have made the question more readable and easier to answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [High CPU usage from jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505611/high-cpu-usage-from-jquery)

Comment: Well, this change could have been made to that previous post of yours and others can easily read the code in history. Nonetheless, I will go back to the other post to see if I can provide my 2 cents.

Comment: Now it's not enough code. You need to make the smallest possible example that replicates the problem – running this code will obviously not do anything.

Comment: Theres some interference causing one of the codes ( or both) not to work properly. Without that code its difficult to find that problem.

Comment: I am sorry guys. I honestly tried to be minimum and sufficient. So this time I put the minimum. All clarifications for the sufficient can be found in the previous post, and the link for that is provided in this question.

Comment: Please declare **all** the variables you use. Especially the index variable when you iterate over Arrays.

Comment: Everything compiles properly without any errors, so my issue cannot variable declaration.

Comment: When two nested loops use the very same variable (`window.i`) to store the index for their iteration, then I wonder that your doesn't produce funny results.

Comment: Can you specify which nested loop you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Thomas pointed out the correct mistake.

"When two nested loops use the very same variable (window.i) to store the index for their iteration, then I wonder that your doesn't produce funny results."